# How do I convert a mesh region back into a Graphics3D primitive?

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

The Graphics3D format has more styling options than mesh based graphics, so I was wondering if there was a way to convert mesh based objects such as region intersections and unions back into the Graphics3D format.

Comment: Could you give us an example of such a mesh?

Comment: `Show[meshregion]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Answer (score 8):

Michaels comment is completely correct. By using `Show`, the region gets transformed back into a graphics, although it doesn't look like that. There is one major difference to my answer: While I'm extracting the polygons and the final `Graphics3D` will only contain these primitives, using `Show` wraps the polygons into an `Annotation[poly, "Geometry"]`.

This is just for your information. Here is how you can extract the polygons and create a new `Graphics3D`:

```
{cube, cone} = DiscretizeRegion /@ {Cuboid[], Cone[]};
reg = RegionIntersection[cube, cone]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
MeshPrimitives[reg, 2] // Graphics3D
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thank you, now I no longer need to worry about using my own functions for rotation and intersection

Answer (score 8):

In Mathematica 12, [`MeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshRegion) and [`BoundaryMeshRegion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryMeshRegion) objects act as graphics primitives in [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D). So:

```
{cube, cone} = DiscretizeRegion /@ {Cuboid[], Cone[]};
reg = RegionIntersection[cube, cone];

Graphics3D[{LightGreen, EdgeForm[None], reg}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It might be more efficient to use a `GraphicsComplex` for regions with many polygons

```
Graphics3D[{
  GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates[reg],MeshCells[reg, 2, "Multicells" -> True]]
  }]
```

Whenever `reg` is a `MeshRegion`, it is also a good idea to first convert it to a `BoundaryMeshRegion` with `BoundaryMesh[reg]`. Otherwise, also all interior (and thus invisible) polygons will be written into the `GraphicsComplex` (and have to be processed by the z-buffer of the GPU during rendering).